# Python SQLite3 is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I am practing using SQLite3 in Python.
The version of Python is 2.7 And I am using mac os.

I cannot find any problem with my code...
When I run it, I do not get any syntax error.
My coding suppose to print out every element of database.
It does not print anything at all.

```
import sqlite3

createDb = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')

queryCurs = createDb.cursor()

def createTable():
    queryCurs.execute('''CREATE TABLE customers
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, street TEXT, city TEXT, state TEXT, balance REAL)''')

def addCust(name, street, city, state, balance):
    queryCurs.execute('''INSERT INTO customers (name, street, city, state, balance))
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ''',(name, street, city, state, balance))

def main():
    createTable()

    addCust('test1','123 mel','vancouver','bc', 10000000.00)
    addCust('test2','145 joy','ottawa','on', 10000000.00)
    addCust('test3','521 tick','toronto','on', 10000000.00)
    addCust('test4','5832 tock','burnaby','bc', 10000000.00)

    createDb.commit()

    queryCurs.execute('SELECT * FROM customers')

    for i in queryCurs:
        print "\n"
        for j in i:
            print j
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you call `main()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never *call* your `main()` function. Python doesn't automatically call functions, `main()` has no special meaning. You'd normally add a "script test":

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

to the end of your module to call a function when the file is run as a script; when your file is imported as a module instead `__name__` contains the module name instead of `'__main__'`.

When you do, you'll see you have a SQL syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 18, in main
    addCust('test1','123 mel','vancouver','bc', 10000000.00)
  File "test.py", line 13, in addCust
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ''',(name, street, city, state, balance))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

You have one too many `)` in your SQL following the list of column names, remove it:

```
def addCust(name, street, city, state, balance):
    queryCurs.execute('''INSERT INTO customers (name, street, city, state, balance)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ''',(name, street, city, state, balance))
```